# Syntax Error while installing packages in jenkins

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, python-2.6

I can able to install below packages using python script in my **scp**(Python version 2.7). But in **jenkins** i am getting **syntax error** .

**PYTHON CODE:**

```
VIRT_DIR = "home/user/vitual_dir/"
subprocess.call("pip install --user virtualenv", shell=True)
subprocess.call("python -m virtualenv " + VIRT_DIR, shell=True)
activate_this = (VIRT_DIR + "/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__= activate_this))
subprocess.call("pip install pylint", shell=True)
subprocess.call("pip install coverage", shell=True)
subprocess.call("pip install pytest", shell=True)
```

**Error message in jenkins:(python version 2.6.6)**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/jenkins/vapor/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/home/jenkins/vapor/lib/python2.6/site-
packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/home/jenkins/vapor/lib/python2.6/site-
packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/home/jenkins/vapor/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", 
line 526


    {str(c.version) for c in all_candidates},
                  ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: One of the packages you're using doesn't support Python 2.6. If you want to try to backport it yourself, the problem is that is uses a set comprehension, and those were only added in 2.7 (and 3.x); you'd have to rewrite that line as `set(str(c.version) for c in all_candidates)`. But the simpler answer is that you need to either upgrade to Python 2.7, or not use packages that require 2.7. (Python 2.6 has been out of support for half a decade now.)

Comment: I tired to upgrade python version 2.7 using "pip install python2.7". 
I am getting error. Can i know the right command to updrade in virtual env

Comment: You can't use pip to upgrade Python itself. If you're on Linux, your distro probably has a python 2.7 package in its official repo, in which case you should probably install that with apt-get or yum or whatever. Otherwise, you probably want to download the latest 2.7 installer for your platform from python.org.

Comment: Or, if you already _have_ Python 2.7 on the server, but just created a virtualenv around 2.6 instead, you just need to create a new one with 2.7. See [the docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#virtualenv-command) for details, but it should be something like `python2.7 -m virtualenv --python=python2.7`.

Comment: I tired "python2.5 -m virtualenv --python=python2.5 "  . I am getting python2.5 command not found

Comment: Why would you try `python2.5` to get Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

subprocess.call("python -m virtualenv " + VIRT_DIR, shell=True)

**I used**

**subprocess.call("virtualenv " + VIRT_DIR, shell=True)**

Now , it is working fine. I can able to install python2.7